# Передача сообщений между потоками - C#

Tags: c#, wpf, многопоточность, task

Есть у меня простой класс-логгер:

```
static class Logger
{
    public delegate void Message(string msg);

    static public event Message OnMessage;

    static public void SendMessage(string msg)
    {
        OnMessage?.Invoke(msg);
    }
}
```

Я из любых мест приложения отправляю ему сообщения по типу: `Logger.SendMessage("Получена команда на запуск");`

При загрузке window (WPF) я подписываюсь на события логгера и вывожу лог в `textbox`

Пока приложение было однопоточным всё отлично работало, но теперь методы отлажены и надо всё распараллелить (идет обращение к 40 БД на разных хостах поэтому всё хорошо параллелится)

Но теперь возникла проблема - при попытке прочитать отправленное сообщение из другого потока возникает **Exception**

> "Вызывающий поток не может получить доступ к данному объекту, так как
>   владельцем этого объекта является другой поток."

Как это грамотно и с малой кровью исправить?

Comment: `e.ToString()` в студию!

Comment: Не знаю что вы имеете под `e.ToString()` - если e - это экземпляр exception, то его вывод я выше привел

Comment: `ToString()` выводит всю информацию об исключении, включая стектрейс. Вы привели только сообщение.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Смотрите.

Проблема в том, что события доставляются в том потоке, который отправляет события. Поэтому у вас подписчики событий получают событие каждый раз в разных потоках. Если подписчик — UI-код, который просто выводит текст в UI, то при приходе сообщения из неглавного потока происходит проблема.

Есть несколько путей починки вашего кода.

1. Можно привязать логгер к главному потоку. При этом сообщения будут доставляться только в главном потоке, и соответственно UI-код будет всегда работать «как надо».

   ```
   static class Logger
   {
       static Lazy<Dispatcher> dispatcher =
           new Lazy<Dispatcher>(() => Application.Current.Dispatcher);

       public delegate void Message(string msg);

       static public event Message OnMessage;

       static public void SendMessage(string msg)
       {
           if (dispatcher.Value.CheckAccess())
               OnMessage?.Invoke(msg);
           else
               dispatcher.Value.InvokeAsync(() => OnMessage?.Invoke(msg));
       }
   }
   ```

   Это, наверное, не самое лучшее архитектурное решение, т. к. при этом логгер получается зависимым от WPF, то есть модель получает зависимость от VM (что не позволит использовать её повторно в других программах). Зато этот метод решает задачу наиболее просто: другие переделки при этом не нужны.
2. Можно считать логгер не привязанным ни к какому потоку, тогда UI-код должен проверять, в каком потоке он запущен, и при необходимости пользоваться `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync`.

   ```
   Logger.OnMessage += s =>
       {
           if (Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
               LogContainer.Text += (s + "\n");
           else
               Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => LogContainer.Text += (s + "\n"));
       };
   ```

   Это более правильный подход, но здесь придётся потенциально править все места, где происходит подписка на сообщения от логгера. Впрочем, такое место в программе, судя по всему, одно.
3. Вы можете использовать модные в этом сезоне Reactive Extensions, и переписать ваш класс на них:

   ```
   using System.Reactive.Linq;
   using System.Reactive.Subjects;

   static class Logger
   {
       static ISubject<string> subject = Subject.Synchronize(new Subject<string>());
       public static IObservable<string> Messages => subject;
       static public void SendMessage(string msg) => subject.OnNext(msg);
   }
   ```

   Подписка при этом выглядит так:

   ```
   Logger.Messages.ObserveOnDispatcher().Subscribe(s => LogContainer.Text += (s + "\n"));
   ```

   Максимальная гибкость, LINQ на сообщениях, доставка в произвольный поток, навесные плюшки наподобие подавления слишком частых или повторяющихся сообщений поставляется в комплекте, бонусом ощущение собственной крутости, функциональности и трендовости. Минус — вам придётся-таки разобраться с этим самым Rx (муа-ха-ха!). Или это можно считать плюсом, да. (Think positive.)

   Не забудьте подключить из nuget `System.Reactive.Core`, `System.Reactive.Interfaces`, `System.Reactive.Linq` и `System.Reactive.Windows.Threading`.

Comment: Спасибо, применил второй вариант - все работает как надо. Место в программе пока одно - да, но, как минимум, планируется вывод лога в файл. Так что второй метод логичен и не усложняет саму простоту логгера.

Comment: @Андрей: Пожалуйста!