# Работа с потоками в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, многопоточность

Интересует следующий вопрос: на окне присутствует textblock, информация в котором должна обновляться, к примеру, каждую секунду, для обновления я использую OnPropertyChanged. Операция обновления запускается по кнопке, сам метод обновления привязан с помощью интерфейса ICommand. Понятно, что такие операции должны выполняться в фоновом потоке, пытался сделать через BackgroundWorker, но немного не понял как именно нужно работать с ним, если я использую ICommand. Спасибо.

Comment: `BackgroundWorker` это же старьё. Используйте `TPL`. А для доставки сообщений в поток GUI используйте `Dispatcher`, например: Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => MyText = "some text");

Comment: [Ссылка по теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/564280/218063)

Comment: да я только дошел вот до потоков в WPF, поэтому не знаю, что старье, а что нет)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            //background work
            await Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
            {
                //
                yourProperty=newvalue;//То что связано с GUI (OnPropertyChanged)
            });
 });
```

Comment: спасибо, все работает!!

Answer (score 2):

Альтернативный вариант:

```
async Task DoSomething() // или async void, если это обработчик события
{
    var newValue = await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            // этот код выполняется в фоне
            return result;
        });
    TextBox.Text = newValue;
    // или лучше
    Property = newValue;
}
```

Я пользуюсь тем, что `await`, который происходит в UI-потоке, возвращается назад в UI-поток.