# Задание значения в textbox из других классов, MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, textbox

Есть классическое MVVM приложение VIEW содержит textbox, где `Text="{Binding Message}"` во ViewModel

```
private string _message { get; set; }
public string Message
{
    get { return _message; }
    set { _message = value; OnPropertyChanged("Message"); }
}
```

Как передавать это значение из других классов? Если у меня есть структура типа:

- ModelALL -> ClassA -> ClassB -> ClassC
- ModelALL -> ClassA -> ClassG
- ModelALL -> ClassH

И сообщение надо передать из класса CalssC, ClassG, ClassH

Я делал через `event` типа

```
allModel.textAllModel += AllModel_TextChanged;

private void AllModel_TextChanged(object sender, TextMessage e)
{
    Message = e.message;
}
```

Но если у меня допустим 9 классов из которых надо передавать это сообщение, это надо каждый класс подписать на `event` и в нем объявить `event`.

В ClassA event на который будет подписан ModellAll, в ClassB event на который будет подписан CalssA, в ClassC event на который будет подписан CalssB и т.д.

И вот тут у меня вкрались подозрения что я делаю что то не так.
Как нормальные люди обходят такие ситуации?

Comment: Сформулируйте вопрос попонятнее. Какая конечная цель? Вам нужно передавать сообщения из любого класса в "главную" VM?

Comment: @Андрей Да. Я думал может какой то вспомогательный класс сделать и из него как то передавать.

Comment: Сделайте логгер, для начала можно статический. И отправляйте сообщения `Logger.SendMessage("Message")`, а VM подпишитесь на него и обновляйте свое свойство `Message` в подписчике: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/564280/218063

Comment: @Андрей спасибо 1в1 ситуация как у вас была.

Comment: Ок, позже оформлю как ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Напишите простой класс, который будет выступать посредником между отправителями и получателями сообщений, для начала можно его даже сделать статическим:

```
static class Logger
{
    public static event Action<string> MessageReceived;

    public static void SendMessage(string msg)
        => MessageReceived?.Invoke(msg);
}
```

Теперь все, кому нужно что-то сообщить, просто вызывают метод `SendMessage()`:

```
Logger.SendMessage("Сообщение");
```

В конструкторе своей VM подпишитесь на событие `MessageReceived`:

```
Logger.MessageReceived += OnMessageReceived;
```

и обновите свойство:

```
void OnMessageReceived(string msg)
{
    if (!Application.Current.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => Message = msg);
    else
        Message = msg;
}
```

Обратите внимание на использование Dispatcher - он позволяет обновлять свойства VM в потоке GUI (иначе будет возникать исключение - [связанный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/564280/218063)).

Этот способ удобен еще и тем, что если вы захотите, например, параллельно писать все сообщения в файл - это не потребует глобальных изменений, достаточно будет просто подписать еще одно заинтересованное лицо на событие `MessageReceived`