# C# WPF изменение коллекции из другого потока

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Можно ли изменять коллекцию из другого потока в C# WPF? Я получаю данные в [SerialPort.DataReceived](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived(v=vs.110).aspx) который само собой работает в другом потоке

> MSDN: The E:System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.DataReceived event is raised on a secondary thread when data is received from the T:System.IO.Ports.SerialPort object

Мне нужно добавить в коллекцию 1 элемент, не буду же я всю коллекцию перезаписывать...

Comment: Зачем вы создали новый вопрос? Перенаправляйте событие в поток GUI с помощью диспетчера: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/564285/218063

Comment: `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => myCollection.Add(newValue));`

Comment: Если вы уверены, что предложенный дубликат вам не подходит – отредактируйте вопрос и распишите подробно как и что вы пробовали и что не получается.